# how to unzip .7z file on google colaboratory?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I am trying to solve grocery dataset from kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/c/favorita-grocery-sales-forecasting/data I am unable to unzip the `train.csv.7z` file on google colab.

I have tried 
`!p7zip -d train.csv.7z`
but its giving error 
`/usr/bin/p7zip: cannot read train.csv.7z`

Answer (score 2):

In order to access data, you must first upload the csv.7z file on a drive and give Colab permission to access it. This can be done by,

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

After that, you can access the data in drive.

Example :

If the train.csv.7z is inside a folder called 'train' in Drive, you can access it by running the following

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

After giving access, run the command,

```
!p7zip -d './gdrive/My Drive/train/train.csv.7z'
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: thanks a lot.. this totally worked. actually earlier I was unable to access the directory which has the train.csv.7z file.

Comment: Glad it worked! Can you accept my answer and close the topic?